# How to select using sheets query from a subset in a second range

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have two sheet tabs, "Events" and "People".  One person assigned to each event in the Events tab.  People can be designated as an "Expert" (True or False) on the People tab.

Trying to build a Query on a third tab that results in:

Select all Events that only have people assigned that are experts.

I've tried various iterations of "Lookup" or "Filter" in the query, but I think the proper syntax is defeating me.  Suggestions?

Sample Events sheet:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLAlV.jpg)

Sample People sheet:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfXcn.jpg)

The end result - only Events lead by Tom or Mary, listed separately on a third tab.  Dynamic as new events are added or people added/become experts.

Answer (score 0):

It's challenging to do this without a live link. Below is my attempt:

```
=QUERY(Events!A:D,"select * where D contains '"&JOIN("' or D contains '",FILTER(People!A:A,People!B:B=TRUE))&"'",1)
```

Comment: My apologies, should have included a link to a live sheet!  Works well, but one wrinkle - if a name has an apostrophe, it dies.  I tried substituting double quotes for the single, but no go.  Suggestions?   Link has your solution under results, with the error for the offending name. 
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LxJe0zHlJxlSoW6EdHPY5gslYtrO6rV1bnbGR0TVLsE/edit#gid=23682127

Comment: Figured it out - subbing ALL the single quotes (') for double ("") allowed it to run.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
=filter(Events!A:D,xmatch(Events!D:D,filter(People!A:A,People!B:B)))
```

[image]